# There is no information available for In-App Purchases. Try again later. 21102

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, flutter-in-app-purchase

First of all I found this other related old issue but with different ID but none of the solutions provided worked for me:
[There is no information available for In-App Purchases. Try again later. 21105](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63610039/there-is-no-information-available-for-in-app-purchases-try-again-later-21105)

I'm testing the in app purchases on iOS and now I'm getting this message. I cannot get any of the products I have configured. This was already working before so everything related to configuration wether in my app or in Apple account is fine. On Android everything works fine.

I tried:

- Same account that was working before
- Create new accounts
- Different devices
- Simulators
- Android Studio and Xcode

Some people mention that this is only for sandbox accounts and in production we won't see any of these messages but I need to do some changes on my app so I need to buy some products for that. Also I cannot open the door for new bugs (specially related to paid versions).

Comment: I have the same problem, were you able to solve it? , we migrated this app from unity to flutter, will it be because of the migration?

Comment: you have to try on a real device

Comment: I tried on a real device , did you solve it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I had to try on a real device instead

Comment: im getting this 21102 error on a physical device. not simulator.

Comment: not sure, that was the fix for me sorry